# Sciter shorthand notation

Tags: javascript, operator-keyword, notation, shorthand

I have encountered this notation shorthand in the array.reduce and object.sort functions in Sciter (http://www.terrainformatica.com/) :

```
array.reduce(:a, b: a + b)

object.sort(:a, b: a.start_time < b.start_time ? -1 : 1 )
```

I can pretty much guess what the parameters mean but I don't know for sure.
How does this notation work?

Edit: Similar notation is used in Python. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anonymous_function

Comment: This isn't valid JS, even with the ES6 features available in Babel.

Comment: @ssube This isn't Javascript. It's TIScript (aka Sciter)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently that's a [lambda function syntax](http://sciter.com/docs/content/script/language/Functions.htm) of the *Sciter scripting language*, which might be similar to JavaScript but is very different in this regard.